# NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, jquery

I am trying to call WCF REST service method using Jquery ajax call and getting an error like

```
"NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://localhost:55911/Service1.svc/Testing"
```

Here is my code

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Button2").click(function () {
                 var Input = {
                     UserId: "11111"
                             };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: " http://localhost:55911/Service1.svc/Testing",
                    data: JSON.stringify(Input),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("Success");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert("failure");
                        alert(stattus.toString);
                    }
                });

            });
        });
```

and

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/Testing", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string Testing(int UserId);
```

and

```
  public string Testing(int UserId)
        {
            sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            sqlConn.Open();
            sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("TestInsertion", sqlConn);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@id",UserId);
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConn.Close();
            return "true";
        }
```

What am i doing wrong here??Any suggestion??

EDIT:After commenting  `//contentType: "application/json"` it is posting and throwing

```
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:55911/Service1.svc/Testing"
```

Comment: I am very confused now. Are you trying to use WCF or are you trying to use Web API. Because you have syntax from both and they aren't compatible.

Comment: @Aron am using WCF only..Which one is Web API syntax??

Comment: Web invoke is a web api attribute. I suggest if you want to use that syntax to switch to using asp.net MVC and create a web api controller.

Comment: PS web invoke is likely to do nothing to your wcf contract.

Comment: @Rooney check my updated [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14831359/468718).

Answer (score 1):

- Please check that the HTTP Request method is `POST` at client
  (`html`) and on server (`WCF service`)
- Because the NetworkError 405
  status suggests that the calling code (`html`) is using wrong HTTP
  Method, `WCF service` is working ok.

Please refer: [405 Method Not Allowed Error in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436182/405-method-not-allowed-error-in-wcf)

### Update

**What I believe** is keep the rest of the things (also content type `contentType: "application/json"`) as it is just change parameter type to `string` from `int` in `WCF service`

```
    public string Testing(string UserId)
    {
        sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        sqlConn.Open();
        sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("TestInsertion", sqlConn);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@id",UserId);
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConn.Close();
        return "true";
    }
```

Comment: no still its not working..but its working in Firefox RESTclient

Comment: @Rooney Can you provide your updated javascrpt/jquery code and what is the error message when it is not working and working in FF RESTclient.. ?

Comment: @Rooney or may you have found solution ?

Comment: :i was checking my application using Firefox..It is still not working in Firefox but is working in IE

Comment: what is error message ? May be check the error console in the FF (using `ctrl + shift + J`)

Comment: NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://localhost:55911/Service1.svc/Testing

Answer (score 1):

The `UriTemplate` you defined is wrong, try using it like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/Testing?U={UserId}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string Testing(string UserId);
```

and then in the implementation convert that `UserId` to int as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this errors happens when an exception is thrown at your method so i suggest  to debug

it either by attaching it to process to by writing this line of code at the beginning of the

function

```
Debugger.launch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running both WCF Service Project and Consuming Project (AJAX Call) at the same time (in same instance of Visual Studio)? If so, try two different VS instances and run WCF Project first, then the consuming project. Also, try using `dataType` as `jsonp` instead of `json`.

Comment: No need to comment `contentType`. As Harsh also mentioned, you cannot put `int` type parameter. So, change it to `string`

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the HTTP Request method is POST or OPTIONS. This [link](http://blog.weareon.net/calling-wcf-rest-service-from-jquery-causes-405-method-not-allowed/) will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use JSONP for a cross-domain call to get round the browser restrictions

this answer is very helpful: [WCF error : 405 Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228995/wcf-error-405-method-not-allowed)