# NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed in WCF REST service in Firefox browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, jquery, firefox

Possibly Duplicate : 
[NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827951/networkerror-405-method-not-allowed-in-wcf)

I called a REST service in jQuery AJAX POST. It works fine in IE8. But shows "**NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed**" in **Firefox**. I searched lot of websites but couldnt get a clear answer.

My **Interface** code :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IEShop
{
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/InsertDetails", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
 string InsertDetails(EShopInputParameters EcomInput);
}
```

**Jquery**

```
var postCall = function () {  
var input =
{   
Userid: "123456",
partnerid: "cswp"   
};
alert(JSON.stringify(input));                            
$.ajax({                
type: "POST",
url: "http://localhost:36196/Service.svc/InsertDetails",
data: JSON.stringify(input),
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: "json",
success: function (response) {                        
alert(response);
},
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
alert(error);
}   
});
}
```

**Service**

```
public string InsertDetails(EShopInputParameters EShopInput)
{
try
{
command = database.GetStoredProcCommand(Data_Template.UspGetInsertDetails);
database.AddInParameter(command, Data_Template.UserID, DbType.String, EShopInput.Userid);
database.AddInParameter(command, Data_Template.PartnerID, DbType.String, EShopInput.partnerid);
database.ExecuteNonQuery(command);
return "0";
}
catch (Exception err)
{
throw err;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance..

```
**EDIT** <br/>
```

From the blog http://blog.weareon.net/calling-wcf-rest-service-from-jquery-causes-405-method-not-allowed/ I added the below code. But it bypasses the **"if"** condition.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, x-requested-with");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}           
}
```

Comment: Can you check what http Verb firefox is sending to your wcf service?

Comment: @Obaid how to check the http Verb ??

Comment: In Firefox use the Web console (Ctrl + Shift + K). See what http verb is used to call your webservice (POST or OPTION)

Comment: @Obaid . Its OPTIONS http verb. Please check my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer 
From this [link](http://blog.weareon.net/calling-wcf-rest-service-from-jquery-causes-405-method-not-allowed/)

Added the below code in service application. Works well in Firefox.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, x-requested-with");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}           
}
```